# How do I create a BigQuery connection from a file

Tags: java, google-bigquery

In Java, how do I create a connection to BigQuery using a file based authentication approach.

I'm using the new cloud api.

All the examples use

```
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
```

which works in gcloud but not on-prem.

In the old API I could use:

```
InputStream credentialsJSON = new FileInputStream("src/main/java/Warehouse/Common/GoogleCredential.json");
      HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
      JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
      GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialsJSON, transport, jsonFactory);

      // Inject the BigQuery scope if required.
      if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
          Collection<String> bigqueryScopes = BigqueryScopes.all();
          credential = credential.createScoped(bigqueryScopes);
      }

      return new Bigquery.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
              .setApplicationName("Warehouse ETL")
              .build();
```

What's the equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable, which you point to your JSON service account key.

When you call `BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();` it will first look for that environment variable, and if it can't find it, it falls back to the `gcloud` auth that has been set on the box you are running on.

See [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/README.md).

---

**Update due to comments**

You can also reference the JSON file directly in your code (see 2nd link above). For example (simply change to be BigQuery service):

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
.setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials
.fromStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/my/key.json")))
.build()
.getService();
```

Comment: So I can't explicitly call it?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Can I explictly reference the json file to construct the Bigquery connection?

Comment: Yes -  how to do that is in the 2nd link I provided. You just need to change the example to be BigQuery, not Storage.